# Value of selX and selY PuzzleView sudoku example

Tags: android, sudoku

Please download the following code :

http://media.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/code/Sudokuv2/src/org/example/sudoku/PuzzleView.java

In the code,

What initial value does `selX` and `selY` take and how? I'm asking this because there is a function call (`getRect(selX, selY, selRect)`)that uses these two variables.. So, basically what values of `selX` and `selY` are passed during this function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their *initial* value will be **0** since no where (in this file at least) is it set to anything else. As far as I can tell from the code you have provided, there is only one place `selX` and `selY` are set.

```
private void select(int x, int y) {
  invalidate(selRect);
  selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8); <------ Here
  selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8); <------
  getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
  invalidate(selRect);
}
```

`selX` and `selY` are only set when the `select(int x, int y)` method is called so I can't really give you the value for them. This means that the values that are passed into `..getRect(selX, selY, selRect)` are whatever the last `select` set them to.

Without knowing where this method is called and what values are passed into it, it's hard to answer your question. I did notice however that the select method is called within these methods

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);

  select((int) (event.getX() / width),
        (int) (event.getY() / height));
  game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
  Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
  return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event="
        + event);
  switch (keyCode) {
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
     select(selX, selY - 1);
     break;
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
     select(selX, selY + 1);
     break;
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
     select(selX - 1, selY);
     break;
  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
     select(selX + 1, selY);
     break;

    ...
```

So it appears that they are set when the user touches the screen or uses the arrow keys.

You could put a breakpoint in here and check it out for yourself